# ExtJS: best way to configure GUI for permissions at startup?

Tags: extjs

I'm working on a 100% ExtJS application; the browser downloads all the JavaScript and a single HTML file once; everything runs in the browser after that.

When all the panels are rendered at startup (i.e., when Ext.onReady() fires) I need some panels to be hidden depending on the user's permissions. **Is there a common/best practice for configuring the GUI at startup depending on user permissions?**

I think one solution might be to have some panels hidden by default. An AJAX call could be made at startup to get user permissions, and then panels could be un-hidden depending on those permissions. However, I suspect there are better solutions.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: I understand that the front-end javascript can't be trusted as the sole mechanism for security checks and that the backend application would need to verify all the actions received from the front-end.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just write a server-side script that outputs privileged client-side code based on the user's authentication status?  Instead of having your client-side code fetch permission data and branch on them, just have the client-side hit a script that outputs the appropriate javascript.

So if you've got a special "SuperAdminPanel" component, the only way the client ever sees the code is if they hit your authentication-aware user-js script, and are recognized as a super-admin.

In the general case, such a script could just echo out the appropriate script for the currently-authenticated user's level.  It could easily be extended to pass code or configuration specific to individual users, as well.